# How to use ethereal to determine what port to open?

Tags: linux, networking, port

Let's say I closed all the ports with iptables and I start a new app like a browser, mumble or any program. Is there a way for me to see with ethereal what ports this application is trying to communicate on so I can open them with iptables ?

Comment: *Ethereal?* If your copy is actually named "Ethereal" and not "Wireshark", it's got to be more than 10 years old...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `netstat -anutpc | grep SYN_SENT` which will give you a continuous output of all apps which are trying to open a communication. You will see the app name, the remote IP and port as data of importance to you.

Comment: awesome, would there be an equivalent for the responding packets, would it be something like `grep ACK` ?

Comment: Better use ESTABLISHED.

Comment: but does it take into account that all the ports are closed in the first place ?

Comment: As long as the ports are closed with iptables you will not see an ESTABLISHED. So you find out the port the remote server listens to and open it in iptables. As long as the port is closed you will not have any responding packets (btw - netstat shows connections and listeners, to see the SYN, ACK, SYN_ACK you need to use tcpdump or something similar (and of course the ports have to be open). If I misunderstood your question, just let me know.